# why is my question downvoted?

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes

I have [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194638/calligra-not-working-on-xfce) question but don't know why it's downvoted, I really searched , nothing on google says about calligra on xfce.

I'm a new linux mint user, I don't know much about desktops(I only tried cinnamon and xfce).

so why it's downvoted ?

Answer (score 5):

The downvote is from me. While reviewing your post, and applying the bare minimum of markup for code to get things somewhat more readable, I found that your question is still not clear to me (and being unclear is one of the reasons indicated when hovering above the downvote arrow).

I often write something about my downvote when I do. But not always, e.g. if there is already someone who made a remark in a comment to the same effect as I would write. I'm not sure why I didn't do write a comment on this post. Maybe a comment that was there was removed, but more likely I got distracted after editing your question and downvoting  (around that time one of the drives in my  RAID-6 drives decided to go off-line).

As a reconstruction as to the reason why I down voted:

- the multiple references to searching you make are not contributing to a clear question
- there is seldom a need to write a PS, just edit your post to get it into shape and make it easy on the reader instead of on yourself.

My suggestion: reread the post. Remove any part that will not help a potential answerer to answer your question (e.g. the whole sentence "Anyway I searched and didn't find out what files calligra needs." If you want to know which files `calligra` needs, just ask that, don't tell us about your searching efforts).

Look at statements like "I may have known that Calligra needs some KDE files". *You may have known?* Does that mean you knew, but don't know any more? Or you knew and consciously didn't install them (and `apt-get` did not pull them in automatically). That kind of statements do not add to the questions, it just makes it unclear.

My apologies for not giving a reason where I could have. On the other hand realise that one is not required to do so on this site.

Please don't take things to personal if you get a downvote. If you get multiple downvotes on a question, if the question gets closed/put on hold, or doesn't get any answers: look it over if it could be improved upon. Read at least the [help tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) (I can see from your badges that you haven't) and spent a few minutes on how we mark up text that allows you to make your post more readable.

Apart from that, a Sunday (and especially not Easter Sunday) is not a day I would recommend for posting and hoping to get a quick answer, far fewer people online than during weekdays and once new questions pile on top of yours, there is IMO less chance of it getting answered. Caligra has not come up before as far as I can remember, so you might not get an answer because nobody here uses it or knows enough about it.

Don't get discouraged by this, even if your question doesn't get answered. Try again if you have something else, we normally are helpful (although sometimes critical) bunch, especially if you show that you put in some effort yourself. In parallel you can always reap the benefits of others who posted here similar problems to what you may encounter and already got an answer.

Welcome to U&L.

Comment: sorry but it's really my english, "I may have known" meant "I knew" for me but you're right, for an english , this seeems confusing. I edited my post

Comment: The reason I didn't read tour is because I read it on stackoverflow, I thought here is the same(and sort of it was) , and thanks for your answer :)

Comment: apologies accepted :)